# Lost frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having regularily issue with hvc1 videos getting an inconsistent number of frames between ffprobe info and ffmpeg info, and I would like to know what could be the reason of this issue and how if it's possible to solve it without re-encoding the video.

I wrote the following sample script with a test video I have

I split the video in 5 sec segments and I get ffprobe giving the expected video length but ffmpeg giving 3 frame less that expected on every segment but the first one.

The issue is exactly the same if I split by 10 seconds  or any split, I always lose 3 frames.

I noted that the first segment is always 3 frame smaller (on ffprobe) than the other ones and it's the only consistent one.

Here is an example script I wrote to test this issue :

```bash
# get total video frame number using ffprobe or ffmpeg
total_num_frames=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -count_packets -select_streams v:0 -print_format json test_video.mp4 | jq '.streams[0].nb_read_packets' | tr -d '"')
echo $total_num_frames
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i test_video.mp4 -vsync 2 -f null -

# Check ffprobe of each segment is consistent 
rm -rf clips && mkdir clips && \
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 5 -map 0 clips/part_%d.mp4
count_frames=0
for i in {0..5}
do
    num_packets=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -count_packets -select_streams v:0 -print_format json clips/part_$i.mp4 | jq '.streams[0].nb_read_packets' | tr -d '"')
    count_frames=$(($count_frames+$num_packets))
    echo $num_packets $count_frames $total_num_frames
done
```

Output is the following

```
3597
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:59.95, start: 0.035000, bitrate: 11797 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 11692 kb/s, 60.01 fps, 60 tbr, 19200 tbn, 19200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 91 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, nv12, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s16le
frame= 3597 fps=788 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:59.95 bitrate=N/A speed=13.1x    
video:1883kB audio:5162kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

then

```
297 297 3597
300 597 3597
300 897 3597
300 1197 3597
300 1497 3597
300 1797 3597 <--- output are consistent based on ffprobe
```

But then if i check segment size with ffmpeg with the following command

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i clips/part_$i.mp4 -vsync 2 -f null -
```

for part 0 its ok

```
frame=  297 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.95 bitrate=N/A speed=12.5x    
video:155kB audio:424kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

for all other parts it's inconsistent and should be 300

```
frame=  297 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.95 bitrate=N/A speed=12.3x    
video:155kB audio:423kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

The issue is exactly the same with any other interval size, e.g with 10 seconds I would get the following video size:

ffprobe 597 - 600 ...
ffmpeg 597 597 ...

I thought it could be related to source vfr or cfr but I tried to convert the input to cfr and nothing changes.

Moreover I tried to force key frame at every second to check if it was a keyframe issue with the following arg :  -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)", but the problem is exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong ? it happens to me a lot with files in hvc1 and I really dont know how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578206/inconsistent-frame-number-with-ffmpeg

The source of the differences is that FFprobe counts the **discarded packets**, and FFmpeg doesn't count the discarded packets as frames.

---

Your results are consistent with video stream that is created with 3 B-Frames (3 consecutive B-Frames for every P-Frame or I-Frame).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types):

> I‑frames are the least compressible but don't require other video frames to decode.
> P‑frames can use data from previous frames to decompress and are more compressible than I‑frames.
> B‑frames can use both previous and forward frames for data reference to get the highest amount of data compression.

When splitting a video with P-Frame and B-Frame into segments without re-encoding, the dependency chain breaks.

- There are (almost) always frames that depends upon frames from the previous segment or the next segment.
- The above frames are kept, but the matching packets are marked as "discarded" (marked with `AV_PKT_FLAG_DISCARD` flag).

---

For the purpose of working on the same dataset, we my build synthetic video (to be used as input).

Building synthetic video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x256:rate=1 -vf "setpts=N/60/TB" -g 60 -vcodec libx265 -x265-params crf=28:bframes=3:b-adapt=0 -tag:v hvc1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 20 test_video.mp4
```

- `-g 60` set GOP size to 60 frames (insert a key frame every 60 frames).
- `bframes=3:b-adapt=0` force 3 consecutive B-Frames.

For verifying the number of I/P/B frames, we may use FFprobe:

```
ffprobe -i test_video.mp4 -show_frames -show_entries frame=pict_type
```

The output is like:

`pict_type=I`
`pict_type=B`
`pict_type=B`
`pict_type=B`
`pict_type=P`
`pict_type=B`
`pict_type=B`
`pict_type=B`
`...`

---

Segment the video by time (5 seconds per segment):

```
ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 5 clips/part_%d.mp4
```

FFprobe counting:
`297 1497 1200`
`300 1797 1200`
`300 2097 1200`
`303 2400 1200`

FFmpeg counting:
`frame=  297`
`frame=  297`
`frame=  297`
`frame=  300`

As you can see, the result is consistent with your output.

---

We may identify the "discarded" packets using FFprobe:

```
ffprobe -i part_1.mp4 -show_packets
```

Look for `flags=_D`.
Packet with `flags=_D` is marked as "discarded"
Note: In a video stream every packet matches a frame.

FFprobe output begins with:
`flags=K_`
`flags=_D`
`flags=_D`
`flags=_D`
`flags=__`
`flags=__`
`flags=__`
`...`

For every middle segment, 3 packets are marked as "discarded", and that is the reason for the 3 missing frames in FFmpeg compared to FFprobe.